# How adding select imputs and chekboxes

Tags: search

I have a custom search form. Now I'm using it to filter and get the post ID. I'd like to add in the same form other search criteria and a separate submit button. In particular I need to filter by 3 category-subcategory1-subcategory-2 select imputs, 2 taxonomy-select imputs , tags checkbox inputs. Any idea? My form is:

```
function custom_search_form( $form ) {
  $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div class="custom-form"><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search:' ) . '</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ricerca per codice"  value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
  </div>
  </form>';

  return $form;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'custom_search_form', 40 );
```